# Bachelor thesis - Distributed Systems Video Coding Cloud Computing

Tags: video, cloud, distributed-system, mmo

I would like to begin my thesis(Computer Science/Computer Engineering uni) 
soon and I would appreciate it if you threw some ideas.

I'm interested in Distributed Systems. I find the MMOG architecture quite interesting. Also Object Migration seems intriguing. I read some papers in order to combine the above two but the result projects exceed the workload of 1 person. I find it hard to find something specific get involved with.

Other than that I like video coding. Something in that area would also be nice.
If Cloud computing gets in the mix it would be great!

If you have the time, fire away!
thanks

Comment: If you know java and are relatively good at concurrent programming(or even if you're not but you love clean code) then you can join me at writing a mmog engine in java https://github.com/dnavre/osserc Not much has been done on it and i have lately very little free time but I hope it will some day be useful to someone. I have no idea if this kind of thing can be used as a thesis though :) btw I hope it's going to be distributed in some ways :)

Comment: you might check out openstack as a cloud deployment.  it's free and open source.  devstack.org can give you a great test platform quickly.

as far as video check out ffmpeg-server.  you might find something fun to do there.  the goal with cloud design is generally an elastic approach.  share nothing and scale horizontally.  so consider a scale out scenario for video encoding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am doing video encoding in the cloud as part of a project for my startup. 
Check it out: https://github.com/sportarchive/CloudTranscode

This is a distributed transcoding stack using FFMpeg and Amazon AWS services. I use Simple Workflow (SWF) for parallel processing and Amazon SQS for messaging and event propagation.

The project is still in early stage but with little more work it could become pretty powerful.

Cheers,